# Copy-save a sheet in a new workbook named after contents of some specific cells from that same sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, save, rename

I have a sheet in a workbook (.xlsm) I want to "copy" in a new workbook (.xlsx). In the process, I also need the new workbook to be named after the cells B3 and B5 from the same sheet.

I found codes here and there either to create a new workbook from a sheet, either to rename an existing workbook. I tried to 'mix' it, but I'm stuck with the "Filename:=Name" argument. It returns an error. My only way to name the new workbook is to use "". If someone knows the reason and has any guidance for a fix, it would be appreciated.

```
Sub Copy_Save_Sheet_As_Workbook()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Dim Name As String

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Path = "C:\Users\..." 'That line is not used now. Will try later to work on it.
Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.Activate
wb.SaveAs FileName:=Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlNormal

End Sub
```

== EDIT ==

Here is the modified code after the fix from CATSandCATSandCATS.

```
Sub Copy_Save_Sheet_As_Workbook()

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("B3") & Range("B5") & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("B3") & Range("B5") & ".xlsx"
```

in place of this:

```
wb.SaveAs FileName:=Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlNormal
```

And obviously you can add more things to the file, such as a date:

```
& Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy")
```

Or text:

```
& "1Q2019 - March Budget"
```

And if you do not want to save it in the same location as the file containing the macro, you can just add your "C:\Users..." in place of ThisWorkbook.path.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! I will post an answer soon with your fix.